# Ember Component - Cannot set property tagName of #<Element> which has only a getter

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have updated Ember 2.3 recently. In one of our component, We have used 'tagName' as properties like below:

**export default Ember.Component.extend({
  layout,
  tagName: 'div'
}**

It was okay with old Ember. But in the recent one, I am getting the following error.

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property tagName of # which has only a getter***

Could anybody of you suggest me any clue of the issue.

Comment: are you trying to set tagName when using the component like {{your-component tagName="something"}} ?That´s what the error suggests
The code example shown should throw "Uncaught ReferenceError: layout is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

By default, components are 'div' already. According to [docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/#toc_customizing-the-element) you can change tag name with the next code:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'nav'
});
```